# Missing Step Plugin in Linux Environment Pentaho

Tags: java, mongodb, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I created a transformation with a mongoDBOutput which I run from my Java application. I edited my kettle.properties to add KETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS as explained here [Java Pentaho Exception MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676833/java-pentaho-exception-mongodb). This works fine on my windows machine. However, running it on a linux environment causes issues, This is the error I'm getting:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException:
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

    Step : MongoDbOutput
    Step : MongoDbOutput
    Step : MongoDbOutput
    Step : MongoDbOutput
    Step : MongoDbOutput
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML(TransMeta.java:2931)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2813)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2774)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2759)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2744)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2718)
```

I've however edited the kettle.properties to point KETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS to the plugins directory in the linux environment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this issue by setting the plugin folder in my Java app before initializing the kettleEnvironment as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472517/missing-plugins-found-while-loading-a-transformation-on-kettle).

```
StepPluginType.getInstance().getPluginFolders().add(new PluginFolder(pathToPentahoPlugins, false, true));
KettleEnvironment.init();
...
```